# DRYing up JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, html, coffeescript

I have a couple links and divs I would like to have the same functionality on. Basically, you click on a link/button/anything-chosen-as-the-trigger and the corresponding space slides open.

The markup looks like...

```
<!-- some code -->
<li><a href="#" id="first">First</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="second">Second</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="third">Third</a></li>

<div id="f_i_r_s_t"></div>
<div id="s_e_c_o_n_d"></div>
<div id="t_h_i_r_d"></div>
```

So far, I have tried to refactor

```
// script.js.coffee
$(document).ready ->
  $('#first').click ->
    $('#f_i_r_s_t').slideToggle()

// script.js.coffee
$(document).ready ->
  $('#second').click ->
    $('#s_e_c_o_n_d').slideToggle()

// script.js.coffee
$(document).ready ->
  $('#third').click ->
    $('#t_h_i_r_d').slideToggle()
```

which works, to

```
// refactored_script.js.coffee
hideables = {
  '#first': '#f_i_r_s_t',
  '#second': '#s_e_c_o_n_d',
  '#third': '#t_h_i_r_d'
}

for content_space, link_trigger in hideables
  $(content_space).hide()
  $(link_trigger).click ->
    $(content_space).slideFadeToggle()
```

but the refactored script does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: can you do a console of: test = for content_space, link_trigger in hideables; I think this syntax is wrong. and yes, your naming is just plain wrong. f_i_r_s_t -> seriously ?

Comment: This is perhaps a better question for http://s.tk/review.

Comment: thanks, I used that just for question-purposes. the concept is the link "explodes" the space. My app uses more descriptive terms which I cannot use here

Comment: @Raynos ИΞVΞЯ ...okay, maybe eventually

Comment: You need the parentheses in `for`.

Comment: @LeaVerou in Coffeescript, the parentheses are optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```
<li><a href="#" class="links" id="first">First</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="links" id="second">Second</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="links" id="third">Third</a></li>

<div id="first-content"></div>
<div id="second-content"></div>
<div id="third-content"></div>

$('a.links').click(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').slideToggle()
});
```

Adding underscores to your ID's is just making your problem harder and less dynamic; sure it can be done.  You'd just have to take the ID attr and insert a underscore between each character but ... is all I have to really say about that.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually do

```
<li class="links"><a href="#first">First</a></li>
<li class="links"><a href="#second">Second</a></li>
<li class="links"><a href="#third">Third</a></li>

<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>

$('li.links a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).slideToggle();
});
```

that way you can use the css :target attribute as a failover

Answer (score 1):

I would achieve this that way:

```
<li><a href="#" class=toggler toggle="first">First</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class=toggler toggle="second">Second</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class=toggler toggle="third">Third</a></li>

<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
```

and JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggler').click(function(){
    $('#'+$(this).attr('toggle')).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

It's kind of universal solution, can be used in may ways.